# How to convert Axios data to Fetch body in POST method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, es6-promise

Well this is my Axios POST request:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const [data, setData] = useState({
  number: "",
  password: "",
  code: ""
})

function handle(e) {

    const newdata = { ...data };
    newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newdata);
    // console.log(newdata);
}

function submit(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    const url = 'EXAMPLE';

    Axios.post(url, {
        number: data.number,
        password: data.password,
        code: data.code
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Something went wrong.');
    })
        .then((responseJson) => {

            // console.log(responseJson.number);
            console.log(responseJson);

        }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error + ", Or Please check your internet connection and try again.");
    })
}
```

Which is working fine and I recieve respond from server,
But when I convert it to the Fetch like This:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

const [data, setData] = useState({
    number: "",
    password: "",
    code: ""
})

function handle(e) {

    const newdata = { ...data };
    newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newdata);
    // console.log(newdata);
}

function submit(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    const url = 'EXAMPLE';

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Something went wrong.');
    })
        .then((responseJson) => {

            // console.log(responseJson.number);
            console.log(responseJson);

        }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error + ", Or Please check your internet connection and try again.");
    })
}
```

it doesn't work and when I use Network => Payload tab Request is working just like Axios, But no respond is detected.
Why is that happening? maybe I'm missing something?
My convert is wrong in body?

Comment: Anything in console?

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev Yes, When I use Axios console log is server respond and works.
But using Fetch output in console is SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Comment: try adding `headers: {"content-type": "application/json"}`

Comment: @pguardiario
I just tried it before reading your comment, Well no respond to my request but in Network tab output is 204 no content...

Comment: It seems more like cors issue, do you have cors related errors?

Comment: I'm not sure about that response. Anything in the 2xx range means it was ok in general.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

```
function Foo(){
  let [data, setData] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`some url that has json output`).then(r => r.json()).then(setData)
  }, [])
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
}
```